# How to align labels at same side chartjs React

Tags: chart.js, react-chartjs, react-chartjs-2

Hello i am rendering these charts using chart js but i am unable to align these charts in the same order my config file and options file is given below
can anyone please help me with this. i tried with below options and data

```js
const options = {
    indexAxis: "y",
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    aspectRatio: 0.8,
    barThickness: 20,
    responsive: true,
    layout: {
        padding: {
            left: 1
        }
    },
    plugins: {
        legend: {
            display: false
        }
    },
    scales: {
        x: {
            ticks: {
                color: "#495057"
            },
            grid: {
                color: "#ebedef"
            }
        },
        y: {
            ticks: {
                color: "#495057",
                crossAlign: "near"
            },
            grid: {
                color: "#ebedef"
            },
            gridLines: {
                offsetGridLines: true,
                display: true
            }
        }
    }
};


const data = {
    labels: ["red"],
    datasets: [{
            backgroundColor: "#42A5F5",
            data: [65],
            borderWidth: 2,
            borderRadius: 75,
            borderSkipped: false
        },
        {
            backgroundColor: "#FFA726",
            data: [28],
            borderWidth: 2,
            borderRadius: 50,
            borderSkipped: false
        }
    ]
};
```

how to align one below the other labels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know chart.js does not provide an option to set a minimum distance for the labels, a workaround to achieve this is to add spaces the the labels of the charts where the labels are shorter as the longest one so you will get something like this:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ["                Red"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12],
      backgroundColor: 'pink'
    }]
  },
  options: {
    indexAxis: 'y'
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.0/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var options = {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ["                Red"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12],
      backgroundColor: 'pink'
    }]
  },
  options: {
    indexAxis: 'y'
  }
}
var options2 = {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ["   Yellowwwww"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12],
      backgroundColor: 'pink'
    }]
  },
  options: {
    indexAxis: 'y'
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
var ctx2 = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer2').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx2, options2);
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer2" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.0/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```